# Asking user to plot two columns in a csv file without him typing the entire column name?

Tags: python, pandas

My current code:

```html
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data.csv',index_col=False)


while True:
     print (df)
     print ('Select X-Axis')
     xaxis = input()
     print ('Select Y-Axis')
     yaxis = input()
     break
 
df.plot(x= xaxis, y= yaxis)
```

My current works only if user types out the entire column name. However, some of the columns are large. I want to make it easier for my user so that if he types out part of the column name it works. Or if somehow I can assign each column name with a number without manually going through each column and assigning a number. Then I can show a list to the user and he types out the number he would like to plot.

Comment: Have you tried coding your own suggestion? Try it first and come back if you don't succeed. This is not a free coding service.

Comment: @JulienBernu Well if I know how to start I would, like my current code. It is why I asked here for some help for direction. I never asked anyone to write my entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do is to use filter in pandas for that purpose.

```
df.filter(regex=(yaxis))
```

It will display all the columns matching that substring of yaxis

here is an example.

```
A = { 'Name': [ 'John', 'Andrew', 'Smith'] , 'Age' : [20,23,42]}

A
Out[19]: {'Age': [20, 23, 42], 'Name': ['John', 'Andrew', 'Smith']}

df = pd.DataFrame(A)

df
Out[21]: 
   Age    Name
0   20    John
1   23  Andrew
2   42   Smith

df.filter(regex=('Na'))
Out[22]: 
     Name
0    John
1  Andrew
2   Smith

df.filter(regex=('e'))
Out[23]: 
   Age    Name
0   20    John
1   23  Andrew
2   42   Smith
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused on what you mean by this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Whenever I try to graph it, the graph window crashes causes me to restart. So I did a print(df.fliter(regex=('yaxis')) to see what is in it and I get Index : [0,1,2,3,4..... and so on.

Comment: use df.filter(regex=(yaxis)).head(10) to check only first 10 rows and verify your output

Comment: I left the plot for a bit and it tried to plot everything with the x axis i picked